# How do I tell what version of Cassandra I'm running?

Tags: amazon-ec2, debian, cassandra

I just spun up a machine on EC2 running Cassandra following the instructions in the link below, but I have no idea what version it is.  How do I figure this out?  I know I'm missing something incredibly simple, just don't know where to look.

http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CloudConfig

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reviewing the instructions you listed, it looks like you're on a Debian(-based) system.  In particular, in the "Cassandra Basic Setup" section, it says:

```
Step 3. Install the Debian package for Cassandra

% apt-get update % apt-get install cassandra

At this point, Cassandra will be installed and running. However, it's not configured for a multi-node cluster. So we need to continue.
```

If you followed this step to install Cassandra, you can simply use Debian's package management tool to inquire about the package you installed:

```
% dpkg -s cassandra
```

Comment: This will get you the debian package version.

Answer (score 47):

It might be easier to use *nodetools*

```
./nodetool -h localhost version
```

Comment: Awesome! A sample output of mine is `$ ./nodetool -h <server_name> version
ReleaseVersion: 1.2.6.6`

Answer (score 15):

You could use *cqlsh*.

```
$ cqlsh

Connected to Test Cluster at localhost:9160.
[cqlsh 3.1.8 | Cassandra 1.2.18 | CQL spec 3.0.5 | Thrift protocol 19.36.2]
Use HELP for help.
```

Answer (score 8):

May also use "SHOW VERSION" command in CQL:

```
cqlsh:mydb> SHOW VERSION ;
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.2 | CQL spec 3.2.0 | Native protocol v3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the `describe_version()` method.

http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/API#describe_version

Answer (score 2):

You could query your package manager:

```
dpkg -l cassandra
```

or

```
yum info cassandra
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to Cqlsh command prompt and type `show version` to get the version of cassandra you are using